# How to pass an object to service constructor in NgModule of angular 2/4 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

So here is a service say MyService

MyService has a constructor in its implementation

```
@Injectable() 
export class MyService {
    constructor(myObject: MyClass) {}
}
```

Now myObject is of type MyClass which I need to pass while injecting the service

One way by which I can use MyService is

```
_myService = new MyService(new Myclass())
```

and then access methods in MyService

```
this._myService.someMethod();
```

But with this approach I have to do this in every component where I use MyService

I want to pass the value to MyService constructor in NgModule in providers array

So that in any component I need MyService I can just use by

```
export class MyComponent {
    constructor( _myService: MyService) {}
    this._myService.someMethod();
}
```

Comment: Your `Myclass` instances are different for each component ?

Comment: No they are the same. I tried using useFactory and return new MyService(new Myclass()) in it but it did not work in the component where i had constructor( _myService: MyService) {} and this._myService.somemethod() threw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it

It can be done by using useFactory in the following manner

```
{
  provide: MyService, 
  useFactory: MyServiceFactory  
}

export function MyServiceFactory() {
  return new MyService(new MyClass());
}
```

This will pass the MyClass object which is required by MyService constructor and the service can be injected henceforth into any component.

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor( _myService: MyService) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make the `Myclass` object also an injectable using [***ValueProvider***](https://angular.io/api/core/ValueProvider)

```
{ provide: Myclass, useValue: new Myclass() }
```

and add it to the providers. Then DI mechanism can know about the `Myclass` type and inject correctly. The constructor of service must provide the type for the parameter

```
export class MyService {    
   constructor(myObject: MyClass) {}    
}
```

and inject `MyService` as you want

```
export class MyComponent {
   constructor( _myService: MyService) {}
}
```

Also you can just create that instance in the service if it is the same for all of them and omit from the constructor.

Comment: My understanding is ValueProvider essentially assigns the value. But I want to pass MyClass instance as argument to MyService constructor. console logging this._myService in MyComponent returned me MyClass which means MyClass value was assigned to MyService. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Why you need to manually create your parameter when the constructor will inject `MyService` and it in it's case will inject `Myclass` object?

Comment: Implementations of MyService and MyClass are external and are coming from a imported library. I just want to consume it in MyComponent and many other components

Comment: Basically after following whatever you have said and doing this._myService.someMethod() is giving me an error in MyComponent but doing  _myService = new MyService(new Myclass()) in MyComponent is working fine whenever i try to access a method

Comment: Provide an Stackblitz